# Error with  selected item from the ListBox property (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < countSelected; counter++)
        {
            string groupName = txt_GroupName.Text;
            //Get GroupID from the created group
            string GroupIDQueryText = "SELECT GroupID FROM tbl_group WHERE GroupName ";
            int groupID = Convert.ToInt32(server.performQuery(GroupIDQueryText, groupName, MySqlDbType.VarChar));
            //To get User ID
            string firstName = ListBoxMembers.SelectedItems[counter].Value;
       }
```

This isn't returning the selected value, but instead returns the 1st person in the list even if I haven't selected it. Where am I going wrong?
System.Web.UI.WebControls does not contain defenition for listboxmembers.selectedItems error

Comment: It is really not a good idea to perform a query inside a loop, as this will really hurt performance.  It's better to collect all id's first, and then use them in one single query.

Comment: @Frederik Gheysels thats very true!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `.Items` which is the collection of all items in the `ListBox`. I think you intend to use `.SelectedItems` ([documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx)).

```
// When counter = 0, this is the very first item in the listbox
ListBoxMembers.Items[counter].Value;

// When counter = 0, this is the first of the selected items in the listbox
ListBoxMembers.SelectedItems[counter].Value;
```

**EDIT** Web ListBox controls are different than WinForms ListBox controls, so knowing that context is very valuable. Here's an article from MSDN on [how to determine the selected items in a multi-selection list control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5kfekd2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (scroll down to the multi-selection section). The idea is to loop through all `.Items` and check the `.Selected` property on each.

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls does not contain defenition for listboxmembers.selectedItems error

Comment: @Mark I didn't realize you were in WebControls, so my answer was for a WinForms ListBox. See my edit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `ListBox.SelectedValue("Somval");` to set selected Value

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

If you have multiple listbox members, like

```
#  | Name | Selected
0  | a    | false
1  | b    | false
2  | c    | true
3  | d    | true
```

then your `for` loop with `counter = 0` selects the entry `(0,a,false)` and not `(2,c,true)` at

```
string firstName = ListBoxMembers.Items[counter].Value;
```

You have to map the value of the variable `counter` to the `counter+1`-th selected item or use `SelectedItems`, as mentioned by David.